# Implementing Accordion using Vaadin 6

Tags: java, vaadin

I am new to Java and have taken a course fundamentals for it.  Currently I am using vaadin as my framework to create a simple webapp but am running into problems with implementing the accordion.  I would like some pointers in my code, there is an error with casting accordion to component in the main app.

My current code so far:

Main java class:

```
package Main;
import UI.Accordiontest;
import com.vaadin.ui.SplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;


public class test extends Application {

    private SplitPanel horizontalSplit = new SplitPanel(
            SplitPanel.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    private Accordiontest accordion = new Accordiontest(this);

    public void init() {
        buildMainLayout();
    }


    private void buildMainLayout () {
// error: cast accordion to Component
        horizontalSplit.setFirstComponent(accordion);
//error end
        setMainWindow(new Window("test))'
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(horizontalSplit);
        layout.setExpandRatio(horizontalSplit, 1);
        getMainWindow().setContent(layout);
```

UI accordiontest:
   package UI;

```
import Main.test;
import com.vaadin.ui.Accordion;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;

public class Accordiontest extends test{
    public Accordiontest(test app) {
        final Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5;
            i++) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        accordion.addCOmponent(layout);
        layout.setCaption("tab" + (i + 1));
        Label label = new Label("These are the contents of Tab " + (i + 1) + ".");
        layout.addComponent(label);
        TextField textfield = new TextField("some text field");
        layout.addComponent(textfield);
         }
      } 
   }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do, do you want just to add `Accordion` to your page? There are some logic mistakes in your code.
At the error line: `horizontalSplit.setFirstComponent(accordion);`
You are trying to add `accordion` which is object of type `Accordiontest` which extends `test` class and that `test` class is your `Application` class and of course it is not a component.

So there is a problem with your inheritance hierarchy there. But if you just want to add that `Accordion` to your application you can do something like this:

```
package Main;
import UI.Accordiontest;
import com.vaadin.ui.SplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;


public class test extends Application {

    private SplitPanel horizontalSplit = new SplitPanel(
            SplitPanel.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    private Accordiontest accordion = new Accordiontest();

    public void init() {
        buildMainLayout();
    }


    private void buildMainLayout () {
// No more casting errors because accordion extends Accordion which is component
        horizontalSplit.setFirstComponent(accordion);

        setMainWindow(new Window("test))'
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(horizontalSplit);
        layout.setExpandRatio(horizontalSplit, 1);
        getMainWindow().setContent(layout);
    }
 }
```

Then,

```
import Main.test;
import com.vaadin.ui.Accordion;

public class Accordiontest extends Accordion {
    public Accordiontest() {
        super();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TextField textfield = new TextField("some text field");
            addTab(textfield, "Tab" + (i+1), null);
         }
      } 
   }
```

Comment: When creating the labels, I am running into trouble.  In the Accordiontest class, I am adding Label 1 = new Label("1");